# Cлой поверх кнопки

Tags: jquery, html, css

Доброго времени суток! Хочу сделать, чтобы при наведении на кнопку, поверх нее появлялся полупрозрачный слой. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Ps: кнопка сделана div`ом со своим background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Смотрим пример здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/huPzD/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">КНОПКА</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    background: #036;
    color: #FF0;
}
.opacity_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var oBlock = '<div class="opacity_block"></div>';
$('.button').mouseenter(function(){
    var but = $(this);
    but.after(oBlock);
    $('.opacity_block').css({
        top: but.offset().top - but.height() / 4,
        left: but.offset().left - but.width() / 4,
        opacity: 0.5
    });
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.opacity_block', function(){
    $(this).effect('explode');
});
```